# iText.Kernel.Exceptions.PdfException: 'Unknown PdfException.'

Tags: c#, pdf, export

I have an error and this is what it says:

**NotSupportedException: Either com.itextpdf:bouncy-castle-adapter or com.itextpdf:bouncy-castle-fips-adapter dependency must be added in order to use BouncyCastleFactoryCreator**

Here's the code:

```
private void generateReportsToPDFToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    using (PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("output.pdf")))//this line is giving me an error
    {
        using (Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc))
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    doc.Add(new Paragraph(cell.Value.ToString()));
                }
                doc.Add(new AreaBreak());
            }
        }
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Data exported to PDF successfully!");
}
```

I want to generate a report to PDF from my database in SQL. I don't know if I miss something or I need to download some packages.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It seems your application is missing the necessary Bouncy Castle libraries as dependencies for iText 7